# NodeJS : Differences between http.createServer and express.createServer?

Tags: node.js

1/ .createServer from module "http"
2/ .createServer from expressjs
--> which is better ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616153/what-is-express-js

Answer (score 1):

Expressjs builds on top of http.createServer. I would recommend using expressjs as it's far easier.

Answer (score 1):

Expressjs wraps and extends http in Node.

However, based on the question, you should be aware that `express.createServer()` is loooong deprecated.

Express 3.x simply requires `server = express()`