# Making website with Node.js without framework

Tags: node.js, frameworks

i want to create a website based on node js and mysql , but i've read that there is a framework called express for node js , and i'm wondering if i must to use such kind of a framework to create a decent website or it is possible without it and just work with pure node js.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No framework is required.  You can write a full-blown web server using only the `http` module or if you really want to write everything yourself, you can even do it with only the `net` module.

It's really about what is the most effective use of your time and skill as a developer.  Except for academic or pure learning experience reasons, if you're just trying to accomplish a task as efficiently as possible and free, pre-existing, pre-tested code exists that makes your job easier, then that's a better way to go.

For example, if I need to do a file upload from a browser to my back-end and the data is coming in as the multipart/formdata content-type from the browser, I have zero interest in reading and learning the multipart/formdata RFC then writing my own code to parse the multipart/formdata content-type.  Pre-existing, already tested code exists to do that for me and I'm adding no value to the goals of my project by re-implementing and then testing it all myself.  Therefore, I'd like to use a pre-built module that does all that for me.  I can just configure the right library on the right route and out plops my uploaded file in only the amount of time it takes to understand the interface to the 3rd party module and how to use it properly.

This is where Express comes in.  Not only does it offer a useful set of features and architecture for configuring routes, installing middleware, sending responses, using template engines, handling errors, etc... but there are also thousands of third party modules that are built to hook into Express and it is easiest to use them if you're using Express as your core framework.   Some of these modules could be used outside of Express, some cannot - it really depends upon how they're designed and what Express interfaces they do or don't use.

Also, Express is fairly "un-opinionated" and fairly "lightweight" which means it doesn't force you into a particular methodology.  It just offers you easier ways to do things you were already going to have to write code for yourself.

Look at it this way.  When you get node.js, there are thousands of APIs that offer lots of already tested things such as a TCP library, a file I/O library, etc...  Those are frameworks (in a sense) too.  You don't have to use them either.  You could rewrite whatever functionality you need from scratch.  But, you wouldn't even think about doing that because tested code already exists that solves your problem. So, you happily build on top of things that are already done.

One of the BIG advantages of coding with node.js is getting access to the tens of thousands of pre-built modules on NPM that already solve problems that many people have.  Coding in node.js with a mindset that you will never use any outside modules from NPM is throwing away one of the biggest advantages of coding with node.js.

> could you tell me what are the Routes used for in frameworks?

A route is a URL that you wish for your web server to respond to.  So, if you want `http://myserver.com/categories` to be URL that your server responds to, then you create a route for `/categories` so that you can write code for what should happen when that URL is requested.  A framework like Express allows you to create that route very simply with just a single statement such as:

```
app.get('/categories', function(req, res) {
    // put code here to handle that request
});
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg for what Express supports.  It allows you to use wildcards in route definitions, identify parameters in urls, create middleware that does prep work on lots of routes (such as check if the user is logged in), etc...

Comment: *... but it also opens the door to using tens of thousands of pre-built, open source modules on NPM for solving common problems.*  You CAN use available npm modules without Express, just install and require them to your own custom modules. Also we shouldn't underestimate the importance of the learning experience of anything *per se*. If we do, we will miss possible benefits from using it where advantageous - and failures when we don't appreciate its limits. A Node tutorial without Express: https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a framework but it is recommended to use one of them since frameworks like Express make your life easier in many ways. Check this: [What is Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616153/what-is-express-js)

Comment: could you tell me what are the Routes used for in frameworks?

Comment: You can check it from here: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html It basically helps you about how to respond to the client accordingly.

Comment: You see, this is typical the sort of question that a person new to Node.js *and* to Express will be forever asking. Express is coded to deal with the way Node.js operates and it does so in the most sophisticated way that the JavaScript of the day will allow. But Express provides no detailed explanations for it does or why it it codes it the way it does. So the learner wanting to implement a similar effect can only copy the Node-Express code example he sees somewhere. There is no *real* learning experience in that. Better to learn Node.js without Express first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you CAN write a Node.js-based backend without any back end implementation framework such as Express. And if you are using Node.js for the first time without any previous experience of asynchronous coding, I'd advise against using Express, KOA or other Node implementation frameworks for your simple learner apps (e.g. those needing things like register/login form processing, logout button, user preference updates to database, etc) because:

(1) Node.js is a *core skill* for JavaScript back ends.

Stupid analogies between server tasking and restaurant waiters are no use to a real web engineer. You must first know *what* exactly Node can/cannot do in the server CPU that makes it different to most other back end technologies. Then you have to see *how* the Node process actually does this. Using Express/KOA/Hapi/etc you are sometimes effectively removing the mental challenges that come with a Node back end. Any time-saving is achieved at the expense of gaining a proper working understanding of what Node is and how it really operates.

(2) Learning Node.js and its asynchronous coding is hard enough without the added                                    complication of coding with an unknown framework like Express/KOA that assumes users' familiarity with JavaScript constructs like callback functions and Promises. It's always better to learn something in isolation so you get the essence of its individual effects, rather than the overall effects if used with other packages/frameworks. So many of these Node.js Express tutorials are the software equivalent of learning to make a cake by watching Momma do it. We can copy it but we don't know how or why it's working. Professional coders can't just be good copycats.

(3) Available learning tutorials using Express often drag in other technologies like MongoDB, Mongoose, Mustache, Handlebars, etc that make learning Node.js even more awkward still.

(4) A share of basic web apps can be written more efficiently with Node.js, custom JS and existing JS modules imported off the npm repository rather than with Express.

(5) Once asynchronous coding and the JavaScript constructs available to assist with it are understood clearly, pure Node.js apps for basic tasks aren't that hard.

(5) *After* you do get your head around Node.js and can get basic web app functionalities working using server-side JavaScript constructs, you can then *judiciously* start to explore Express/Hapi/KOA/etc and see what an implementation framework can do for your workflow when doing larger projects needing numerous functionalities. At this point you know what Express code should be doing and why it is done the way it is.

Node.js has become the back-end technology of choice for most small to medium scale web applications over the last 10 years. It is also the major reason why the JavaScript language has evolved from a mere front-end scripting tool with a limited set of Java-aping constructs to the innovative and comprehensive language that it is today. It is also the most popular language in use today. Investing time in understanding the Node server framework, and the latest JavaScript constructs used in Node, is time well spent. Implementation frameworks such as Express, KOA, Hapi, Sails, etc have great benefit when writing more elaborate back ends on the Node.js platform. But all these implementation frameworks are predicated on the behaviour patterns of Node.js. So unless Node itself is understood first, the full utility of Express/KOA/Sails/etc will never be enjoyed.

Try [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgTkNlNsy9gVPkxTJry5zb5V8UwLZhw3q) for the pure Node.js.