# difference between node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to the front end development and modern technologies MEAN/MERN stack, I am confuse about difference between node.js and express can someone outline differences or advantages 
and one can learn express.js directly or it's a pre requisite to learn node.js first?

Comment: Very simply: Express is a framework that runs on Node.  You "import" Express into your Javascript application, you write your application using Express objects and Express APIs ... and then you run it with Node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616153/what-is-express-js)

Answer (score 5):

Node.js is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome’s V8 JavaScript engine. It is used to run JavaScript in ways similar to how the browser runs JavaScript but on servers. Express is a library (called a package in the Node.js ecosystem) that makes it really easy to build APIs or serve files.

Answer (score 3):

**Node.js** is a platform for creating server-side event-driven I/o application using javascript.

**Express.js** is a framework based on node.js for developing web-application using principles and methods of node.js.

In simpler terms, express.js makes handling API requests and server management easier than using only node.js

Answer (score 0):

Express js is built on top of the Node.js framework.

Express js uses node.js itself and provides more features to build applications on top Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Node.js: Node.js is a Javascript runtime environment for executing Javascript code outside of a browser.

Express.js: Express.js is fast and light-weigh framework for building web applications.

You should first learn Node.js and it's core modules like path, fs, os, events and others.
After that you should learn asynchronous Node.js like callback, Promises and async/await.

Then you should learn express framework.